# Correct way to transfer ERC-20 tokens and keeping decimals in count?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

I have a token with 18 decimals, I'm using the OpenZeppelin StandardToken example and have figured out that when I want to send value I have to keep the decimals in count as such: _value * 10**decimals.

```
uint decimals = 18
transfer(_receivers[i], (_amount[i] * 10**decimals));
```

This will send the correct amount of tokens. But I don't want to calculate the decimals every place I use the transfer function.. Is it frowned upon to change the OpenZeppelin `transfer()` function to set the value there to

```
_value *10**18
```

Or is there an other way that is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a temporary variable and calculate the product before passig the value to the `trasnfer` function. There is not problem doing that.

Hope this helps